# JavaFx not showing up in preferences window

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am trying to work with JavaFx for the first time . Right now, I cannot see the option for JavaFx in my preferences window (Eclipse -> Preferences -> JavaFx?) as shown here:
[Preferences Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teLLo.png).
I have Java 1.8.0. installed on my mac.

Comment: There is no such preference page in standard Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse itself does not know anything about JavaFX and in fact it does not have to because a JavaFX program is nothing but a plain Java program.
In order to get some additional tooling you can however install this plugin. [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) This is helpfull but not necessary to write a JavaFX program in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may need to manually look up the repository.

I used this walkthrough to do it [Install efxclipse into eclipse](https://o7planning.org/en/10619/install-efxclipse-into-eclipse)

The actual repository is here (as of Feb 24,2020): [http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.0.0/site](http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-released/3.6.0/site)

You will need to restart your Eclipse instance.